# How to make constraints of class function depends from class instance?

Tags: haskell, types

I've been playing with implementing a wrapper for lists which could be indexed differently.

Basic class of such wrappers:

```
class List l where
  toList :: l a -> [a]
```

Wrappers which supports indexing:

```
class Indexed l where
  indexed :: (Ix i, List (l i)) => l i a -> [(i, a)]
  -- i - type of index
  -- l - type of wrapper
```

Wrapper of lists which can be indexed by `Integral` type:

```
data IdxByIntList i a = (Ix i, Integral i) => IdxByIntList { getList :: [a] }
```

If `IdxByIntList` is instance of `List`, then `i` is `Integral` and `Ix`:

```
instance (Integral i, Ix i) => List (IdxByIntList i) where
  toList = getList
```

Looks like constraint `(Ix i, Integral i)`  in `indexed` function is sutisfied and it's possible to make `IdxByIntList` to be an instance of `Indexed`:

```
instance Indexed IdxByIntList where
  indexed = zip [0..] . getList
```

But it cannot be compiled because compiler cannot deduce
type variable `i` to be an instance of `Enum` and `Num`.

### Edited:

In `indexed` for `IdxByIntList`, `[0..]` has constraint `(Num a, Enum a)` which goes to `zip [0..]` and so on and it goes to `indexed`. So, `indexed` should has constraint `(Ix i, Enum i, Num i, List (l i))` but it's not.

`i` is instance of `Integral`, so it's instance of `Num` and `Enum`.

I want `Indexed` to has general constraints for all it's instances and to
has additional constraints which depends from concrete instance. Here, I want `IdxByIntList` to has constraint `(Ix i, List (l i), Integral i)` on `indexed`. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't put constraints on constructors.

Comment: It works if you add `Integral i` to the constraints on `indexed`, although this probably isn't what you want.  The problem is (I think) that `indexed` needs to work with all `(Ix i, List (l i))`, but you're trying to make it work with `(Ix i, Integral i, List (l i))`.

Comment: @Cubic, it helps me to cut off instances of `IdxByIntList` where `i` isn't `Integral` and `Ix`. Why should I avoid it?

Comment: @bheklilr, yea, looks like you are right. I guess I found an answer. `[0..]` has constraint `(Num a, Enum a)` which goes to `zip [0..]` and so on and it goes to `indexed`. So, `indexed` should has constraint `(Ix i, Enum i, Num i, List (l i))` but it's not. That's why it cannot be compiled.

Comment: You can make it less constrained with `enumerate = go 0 where go i [] = []; go i (x:xs) = (i, x) : go (i + 1) xs`.  This only places the constraint of `Num` on your index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing the class a bit to

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Ix

class Indexed li where
  indexed :: li ~ l i => li a -> [(i, a)]
  -- i - type of index
  -- l - type of wrapper

data IdxByIntList i a = IdxByIntList { getList :: [a] }

instance (Integral i, Ix i) => Indexed (IdxByIntList i) where
  indexed = zip [0..] . getList
```

This makes the class parameter the applied `l i` instead of just `l`, which may be enough for your use.

If you really *do* need the instance to be parametrized on `l`, things get more tricky; I think you then need an associated type family of kind `* -> Constraint`, which requires the `ConstraintKinds` extension, and it gets awkward to express the family instances when more than one class constraint is involved. (I don't know whether it would work satisfactory in practice.)